# Let $X$ be a compact Kaehler manifold. Is the group of holomorphic isometries of $X$ compact?

Tags: smooth-manifolds, complex-geometry, automorphism-group, kahler-manifolds

Let $X$ be a compact Kaehler manifold. Then it was shown by Bochner and Montgomery that, with respect to the compact open topology, $Aut_{\mathbb{C}}(X)$, the group of complex automorphisms of $X$, can be endowed with a structure of complex Lie group. Is it true that the group of holomorphic isometries $Iso_{\mathbb{C}}(X)$ is a compact subgroup of $Aut_{\mathbb{C}}X$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A holomorphic map is an isometry iff it preserves the geodesic distance (the latter implying, as $X$ is compact – that’s not entirely trivial – bijectivity).

Now, the set of geodesic distance-preserving maps $X \rightarrow X$ is compact by Ascoli, and the set of holomorphic maps $X \rightarrow X$ is closed in $C(X,X)$ (for the compact open topology).

So their intersection is compact, and it is $Iso_{\mathbb{C}}(X)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mindlack. Where can I find an argument for "bijectivity"?

Comment: Injectivity is easy. The hard part is to show surjectivity. Let $f$ be such an "isometry" (of metric spaces). The idea is that, for each $x \in X$, you can choose a sequence $n_k$ such that $f^{n_k}(x)$ converges and $n_k-n_{k-1}$ increases.  As $f$ is an isometry, you can check that $f^{n_k-n_{k-1}}(x) \rightarrow x$, so $x \in \overline{f(X)}$. As $X$ is compact and $f$ is continuous, $f(X)$ is closed in $X$, thus $x \in X$. I don't know of any reference, I know it only because it was one of the hardest topology questions I had been given as homework.

Comment: Thanks for your help!